# How to minus this fraction with different denominator?

Tags: systems-of-equations, fractions

We have $$a-c/2b$$ $$\text{minus}$$ $$aY-cY/4b^2$$

This simplifies to $$2ba - 2bc + cY - aY/4b^2$$

But, I don't understand how to do this (new to this kind of maths). I'm confused specifically because the first fraction has $2b$ on the denominator whereas the second has $4b^2$ on the denominator. Since denominators have to be the same to add/subtract, I don't know how to get the 2b to be the same as $4b^2.$

Can anyone walk me through this?

Thanks!

Comment: is this $$\frac{a-c}{2b}-\frac{ay-cy}{4b^2}=$$

Comment: Either learn some MathJax/LaTeX to format your question, or at least use some parentheses so we can see what's in the numerator/denomination of the fractions. As it stands, thus requires some guesswork to make sense. - And your question basically comes down to "what is $\frac{4b^2}{2b}$?

Comment: Yes, it's what you posted @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: What you get is $(2ba - 2bc + cY - aY)/4b^2,$ not $2ba - 2bc + cY - aY/4b^2. \qquad$

Comment: @MathsHelp Multiply top and bottom of the first fraction by $2b$, then both fractions have the same denominator $4b^2$.

Comment: I rolled back the changes to formatting here because they change the intent of the author, and thus reduce the instructive quality of the current answers.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote: $$a-c/2b$$ $$\text{minus}$$ $$aY-cY/4b^2$$

But it appears that what you actually meant was this: $$(a-c)/(2b)$$ $$\text{minus}$$ $$(aY-cY)/(4b^2)$$

In standard usage, $a-c/2b$ means $a$ minus a fraction, and the numerator of that fraction is $c.$

So you have
$$
\frac{a-c}{2b} - \frac{aY-cY}{4b^2}.
$$
The way to do this is first to multiply both the numerator and the denominator of that first fraction by $2b,$ so that its denominator becomes $4b^2.$ Then you have
$$
\frac{2b(a-c)}{4b^2} - \frac{aY-cY}{4b^2}
$$
which becomes
$$
\frac{2ab - 2bc}{4b^2} - \frac{aY - cY}{4b^2}.
$$
Then subtract the numerators:
$$
\frac{2ab-2bc - (aY-cY)}{4b^2}
$$
and then distribute the minus sign:
$$
\frac{2ab-2bc-aY+cY}{4b^2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

it is $$\frac{(a-c)2b}{4b^2}-\frac{aY-bY}{4b^2}=\frac{2ab-2bc-aY+cY}{4b^2}$$

Comment: Thanks, but how do you know to put the 2b in the numerator? What's the rule for this sort of question?

Comment: note that $$a=\frac{ab}{b}$$

Comment: You wrote $ay$ and $cy$ where the original posting at $aY$ and $cY. \qquad$